# I want to finish or kill an activity from another activity

Tags: android

I have 6 activities:

`main`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`, `PersonalDetails` and `NewUser`.

When I am in `NewUser` activity, I am using code like this:

```
personalDetails.finish();
```

But it is still not clearing the `personalDetails` activity from the stack. Below is my code and I want clear only particular activities from stack.

Globally, I have declared:

```
PersonalDetails personalDetails;

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
int id = item.getItemId();
switch (id) 
{

    case R.id.action_view_cart:
            personalDetails = new PersonalDetails();
            personalDetails.finish();
             Intent intentViewBookingCart  = new Intent(this,FourthActivity.class);

intentViewBookingCart.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intentViewBookingCart);
        finish();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add static instance to your Activity like this

```
public class PersonalDetails extends Activity {

public static PersonalDetails sPersonalDetails;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sPersonalDetails = this;
}

}
```

And in your next Activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
int id = item.getItemId();
switch (id) 
{

    case R.id.action_view_cart:
            PersonalDetails.sPersonalDetails.finish()
            PersonalDetails.sPersonalDetails = null;
             Intent intentViewBookingCart  = new Intent(this,FourthActivity.class);

intentViewBookingCart.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intentViewBookingCart);
        finish();
        break;

}
```